# Deriving volume of a sphere using calculus and trigonometry

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

I have seen several derivation of volume of a sphere using calculus in the internet. They all use pythagoras theorem to arrive at the formula. I have certain idea of deriving the volume of sphere using trigonometry, but that approach does not lead to the same result. So I want to know where I made mistake in my reasoning. Here is my approach:

$dV$= $\int\pi x^2 dy$
$dV$=$\int\pi(R\cos\theta)^2(Rd\theta)$
where, $R$ is the radius of the sphere and $\theta$ is the  angle between $x$ axis and line segment from origin to $dV$. This integral is evaluated from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

This similar method is used to calculate total surface area of a sphere, but for some reason does not work here.

P.S. go easy on me I know only high school maths

Comment: Hint: The integral must be $\int \pi (R\cos\theta)^2[\cos\theta (Rd\theta)]$. An even simpler method though, is through $\int 4\pi r^2 dr$

Comment: @AkshatSharma Got it thanks!! But can you explain your reasoning for the second integral you gave?

Comment: That is through taking spherical shells as elements.

Comment: @AkshatSharma Oh yes, thank you so much!!

Comment: @AkshatSharma, $\pi(R\cos\theta)^2$ is the area of the circle, $Rd\theta$ is the vertical displacement. But where does the other $\cos\theta$ come from?